# Jmeter Master-slave Architecture

Tags: jmeter

I have created master-slave Architecture in Jmeter.
While executing test to Remote Server(slave),following error has been occurred.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\POST2878005586489712310.binary (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.writeTo(FileEntity.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.sendRequestEntity(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:207)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:619)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:379)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:465)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If you use any file in your test plan of master machine, you must put the file also in the slave machines too. Please put the file in your JMeter bin directory in each machine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve this issue is to place your binary file (which is used in your test plan) on all servers (Master and Slaves) inside the bin directory of JMeter.

Do not specify any path for the file (i.e CSV File) inside your JMeter test plan i.e. Do not use `C:\Data\Files\test.csv` in your test plan, use the only test.CSV (and place this file in Bin directory). Also, it will be good to keep the test plan too in the bin directory of the JMeter master machine.